# HLS Live stream video doesn't play on first load

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, live-streaming, hlsl

I am trying to live stream in iOS, so steps followed -

1. Initialize the player

   ```
   player                 = AVPlayer()
   player.rate            = 1.0
   player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
   ```
2. Setup player layer

   ```
   playerLayer                 = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
   playerLayer.frame           = self.bounds
   playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
   playerLayer.videoGravity    = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

   if let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers {

       for layer in sublayers {
           layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
       }
   }

   self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
   ```
3. Setup player Item

   ```
   let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: streamingUrl)
   playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
   ```
4. Replace the currentItem in player and play

   ```
   self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: self.playerItem)
   self.player?.play()
   ```

My video plays perfectly fine if I load my player once the streaming has started but **if I load the player before I have started live streaming from backend and then start streaming after sometime it doesn't play the video.**

I tried adding an observer to playerItem's status property but that also doesn't change in the condition mentioned above it only changes if I load the player after streaming has started and everything works fine. So my question is why am I not getting status change of my playerItem? Am I missing something? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if url isPlayable `AVAsset(url: URL).isPlayable`, in your case before you can play `if avAsset.isPlayable { playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset); ... }`

Comment: What should I do in else case? If its not playable, how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if url is playable using `AVAsset(url: URL).isPlayable`, in your case before you can play

```
if avAsset.isPlayable {
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
    ...
}
```

For a better approach, use observers

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var observerContext = 0
    private let player = AVPlayer()
    private var readyForPlayback = false

    private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? {
        willSet {
            playerItem?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), context: &observerContext)
        }

        didSet {
            playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.initial, .new], context: &observerContext)
        }
    }

    private var asset: AVAsset? {
        willSet {
            readyForPlayback = false
            asset?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVURLAsset.isPlayable), context: &observerContext)
        }

        didSet {
            guard asset == nil else {
                asset!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVURLAsset.isPlayable), options: [.initial, .new], context: &observerContext)
                return
            }

            playerItem = nil
            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: KVO
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }

        switch keyPath {
        case #keyPath(AVURLAsset.isPlayable):
            guard asset?.isPlayable == true else { return }
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        case #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status):
            guard let status = playerItem?.status else { return }

            if status == .readyToPlay {
                guard !readyForPlayback else { return }
                readyForPlayback = true
                player.play()
            } else if status == .failed {
                readyForPlayback = false
                if let error = playerItem?.error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        default:
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
self.asset = AVAsset
```

On stop playback

```
self.asset = nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have one doubt. With this logic, whenever AvAsset is playable, playerItem should change its state to readyToPlay. Earlier I added observer on playerItem status that was not working, Any probable reason for that

Comment: For the first time itself AVAsset.isPlayable returns true but video doesn't play

Comment: is the KVO called for `case #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status)` what is the status, can you debug and print `status` and `error` of `playerItem`

Comment: Doesn't get called initially, if I load the player before streaming has started. And Once the streaming starts, KVO starts get calling if If move I move the app in background and come to foreground where I forcefully again say AvPlayer play again

Comment: @AjayKumar have you found any solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @HattoriHanzō have you resolved the issue?